# Ruby on Rails: Proper Syntax for 2 dimensional Array in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, database

I plan to insert a two-dimensional array into the database with ActiveRecord.

The reason why: I want users to select multiple languages and the corresponding language-levels (like how good they speak it). I do not want to have two fields for both languages & language_levels, I want those two to be hooked together from the beginning. Sure, I could hook them together later on the model level, but I want to try it the other way first.

Example:

```
[ ["English",2],  ["German",1], ["Japanese",1] ]
```

I've been able to store one-dimensional arrays, though had no luck with these. Trying to make those accessible using something like `(languages: [][])` in the strong parameters didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you tried using hashes for that?

Comment: No I haven't :P Going for Dannys suggestiion

Comment: This is an awful idea -- there's a reason for database normalisation, you know. How is your query for "All users who speak English at level 2 or above" going to look? How will you ensure data integrity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your intent to do this with sort of minimal effort, but you should definitely consider looking into storing things the *normalized way*.

The intention is – what to do with lang. skills for all your users, once there's a need to rename a language? Say you had `Chinese` language as of the start, but then you've decided to keep two of them, `Chinese (traditional)` and `Chinese (simplified)`. You'd now have to write an error-prone update script.

In case of keeping the languages normalized way, I'd keep three models for consistency:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_skills
  has_many :languages, through: :language_skills
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :language_skills
  has_many :users, through: :language_skills
end

class LanguageSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end
```

Comment: Pro: keeps your database "clean" in that the user can only select languages from a predefined list. (although you can also do that when you keep the language as a string) Contra: who will add the "new" languages? The administrator or the user himself? What if the user wants to add some "weird" language the administrator didn't think about?

Comment: You're right. In that moment I didn't realize I was about to mess up my database :-) Anyhow am I right you intended to have a one-to-many-relationship between the Language and LanguageSkills? I worried the most about what data is getting stored in my database and actually thought it's going to look awful, though I was totally wrong

Comment: @JustBasti this is in fact a many-to-many relationship between users and languages, where `LanguageSkill` represents a join table in the DB

Comment: @DannyVanHoof the con of adding the new languages is no worse with this method than it is with storing the languages as a string, though.

Comment: If this is supposed to be a many-to-many with a join table, shouldn't you use `has_many :languages, through: :language_skill`?

Comment: @MarkThomas sure, initially I omitted redundant associations for brevity. I just added the rest of them.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go for something like

```
User
 has_many languages_skills

LanguageSkill
  belongs_to User

  language: string
  level: integer
```

Then use nested forms to add everything together

I would NOT use multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: Sure ... actually thought about making two additional models for either Language AND Skill, but didn't even came near your conclusion ... :D

Comment: I'd be adding another model for languages as well, I think.

Comment: I would not do that. I would like to refer you to the book "Rails anti-patterns", section "AntiPattern: The Million-Model March", in which they discuss this dilemma. Look at http://books.google.be/books?id=i6mZ0HBDPzsC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=AntiPattern:+The+Million-Model+March&source=bl&ots=pMjbT2J4RJ&sig=gUEqqrZC2JnBraCr9OkqUzg_hj4&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=_TvIUqXXConfswa-5oCoCg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=AntiPattern%3A%20The%20Million-Model%20March&f=false page 79

Comment: The "ideal" way for me would be to offer the user a list of "common" languages, and the "other" selection + a field where he can enter his "other language". That's the approach described in the book